# Jest coverage only for local development

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, nuxt.js

I am trying to figure out how to turn coverage off for my Jenkins builds but leave it on for local dev. Basically I want to still get Jenkins to do my tests but I don't need or want the coverage report that "collectCoverage: true" gives me, I only need that for local development.

My jest.config file looks like this.

```js
module.exports = {
 setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'], 
 moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1', 
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1', 
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    },
 moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'], 
 testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/dist/', '/node_modules/', '/salmon'],
 transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest'
    },
 transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!vuetify)'], 
 collectCoverage: true, 
 snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
 collectCoverageFrom: [
         '<rootDir>/api/**/*.js', 
         '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue', 
         '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue', 
         '<rootDir>/store/**/*.js',
        ], 
  verbose: true
}
```

Comment: Run it from an env var, maybe? For example `collectCoverage: !process.env.CI`. But it seems odd to not want to see coverage in the CI build.

Comment: Do I really need coverage reports in the CI Build? I would think I just want to pass/fail it. Coverage is for developers to work towards, which is why I want it only in local dev. I suppose I could have a coverage threshold that fails builds if it didn't meet that though.

Comment: Failing on a threshold is one reason. Reporting it to some kind of aggregator/dashboard is another. Just being able to see the coverage for a given build right there in the UI is sometimes handy. People might not bother to check it locally, but if you can all see it in CI that applies a bit of positive pressure to think about it.